# zlib compression. avoiding lost compressed data following a power cycle

Tags: zlib

Zlib uses a struct z_stream to retain the state info for a compression. deflateInit(...)  initialises the * z_stream pointer passed in and consecutive calls to deflate(...) use the same z_stream pointer. the struct points to my own non-volatile memory alloc and free functions

If my device powercycled but I retained the z_stream contents, could I restart the compression without loss of data retained in the allocated memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're asking now. No, there is nothing else besides the `z_stream` structure, what it points to, and what that points to in order to continue a deflate operation. All of that is allocated by `malloc()`, except the `z_stream` structure itself, which is created by the application, which I presume you can keep track of yourself.

Comment: Ignore last comment. Please the following...

Hi Mark. The z_stream structure does maintain a pointer to the internal state, i presume that pointer is to the allocated memory and we retained it the allocated memory in non volatile ram.  Is there other allocated memory used by gzlib and not tracked by it. If zlib only uses memory from z_alloc then all pointers will be correct. what do you think?